# spark2.0 error Multiple sources found for json when read json file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

when i use spark2.0 read json file like:

```
Dataset<Row> logDF = spark.read().json(path);
logDF.show();
```

but it failed :

```
 16/08/04 15:35:05 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple sources found for json (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.DefaultSource), please specify the fully qualified class name.
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple sources found for json (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.DefaultSource), please specify the fully qualified class name.
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:249)
```

when I use spark 1.6 it was run correct.
the error tell specify the fully qualified class name , but i cant find which class conflict.

thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure how to fix this but no one would be able to do that unless you should add your dependencies file here.

Comment: Try `spark.read().format("json").json(path);`. I was facing something similar for csv and found https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/367

Comment: you have multiple version of spark sql dependency

Comment: how did you resolve this? Same problem here

Answer (score 1):

I came across this and found below to work for me.

```
df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat").load(path)
```

More details can be found here https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/issues/147